# Open link on click with jquery after att id append

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys i have a situation like this

```
<div class="todos-pedidos" title="/pedidos">See More</div>
```

When click this div its expand my UL / LI with this jquery

```
$('.todos-pedidos').click(function() {
$('#bloco-pedidos-andamento ul li:hidden:lt(2)').slideToggle();

if( ! $('#bloco-pedidos-andamento ul li').is(':hidden') )
    $('.todos-pedidos').html("<span class='todos-pedidos2'>See All</span>");
return false;
```

when there is no more LI to expand the button change the div text

so i m try for after change the text from see more to see all if the visitor clicks again this go to a url

i tried like this but i think there is some error or conflict, the link dont open

```
$("span.todos-pedidos2").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var link = $('.todos-pedidos').attr("title");
    location.href=link;
});
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Do you have any errors in your developer console?

Comment: @ChrisHayes no jquery erros, nothing happen. i tried using a alert but dont work.

Comment: instead of location try window.location. Are you sure that you are referring the correct property for redirection?

Comment: See my answer below. @MohammadGoudarzi is also correct that you should use `window.location` for redirection.

Comment: @MohammadGoudarzi o tried window.location dont work, also i did try the url direct on jquery and not works.

Comment: The answer I voted is correct. You should use "live" or "on" for attaching the click delegate to the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are generating the element using JavaScript, you should delegate the event, from one of static parents of the element or document object.

```
$(".todos-pedidos").on('click', 'span.todos-pedidos2', function(event){
// or $(document).on('click', 'span.todos-pedidos2', function(event){
```

Answer (score 1):

The `click` method in jQuery is intended for always-existent DOM elements. Dynamically added elements should use the `on` method to add event handlers:

```
$("span.todos-pedidos2").on('click', function(event) { });
```

Comment: That's correct however we don't know that where is the assignment of handler. If it is after appending the element, the code will work fine as you already may know. Also I think using "live" is better for compatibility issues. ;)

Comment: This doesn't delegate the event. @MohammadGoudarzi `live` is deprecated. _the code will work fine as you already may know_ no, he is appending the element within click handler, so event delegation is necessary.